# remover valores duplicados em array multidimensional

Tags: php, cakephp-2, array-multidimensional

Possuo um enorme array multidimensional e necessito remover valores duplicados com PHP ou alguma função que faça isso quanto utilizado CakePHP. Estrutura do array:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Advertencia] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [tipo_punicao] => CA
                [suspensao_data_inicio] => 
                [funcionario_matricula] => 
                [advertente_matricula] => 
                [recebedor_RH_matricula] => 
            )

        [Funcionario] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [matricula] => 5444
                [nome] => ANDRE
                [quantidade] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Advertencia] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [tipo_punicao] => A
                [suspensao_data_inicio] => 
                [funcionario_matricula] => 
                [advertente_matricula] => 
                [recebedor_RH_matricula] => 
            )

        [Funcionario] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [matricula] => 5555
                [nome] => JOAO 
                [quantidade] => 
            )

    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Advertencia] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [tipo_punicao] => RC
                [suspensao_data_inicio] => 
                [funcionario_matricula] => 
                [advertente_matricula] => 
                [recebedor_RH_matricula] => 
            )

        [Funcionario] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [matricula] => 5555
                [nome] => JOAO
                [quantidade] => 
            )

    )
)
```

Perceba que dois destes dados do array possuem a mesma informação, ou seja `[1]` e `[2]` - onde o `nome`, `matricula` e `id` são iguais. Eu gostaria que um destes dados fosse removido. Não importa qual dos dois irá permanecer. Ficaria assim, por exemplo:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Advertencia] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [tipo_punicao] => CA
                [suspensao_data_inicio] => 
                [funcionario_matricula] => 
                [advertente_matricula] => 
                [recebedor_RH_matricula] => 
            )

        [Funcionario] => Array
            (
                [id] => 25
                [matricula] => 5444
                [nome] => ANDRE
                [quantidade] => 
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Advertencia] => Array
            (
                [id] => 
                [tipo_punicao] => A
                [suspensao_data_inicio] => 
                [funcionario_matricula] => 
                [advertente_matricula] => 
                [recebedor_RH_matricula] => 
            )

        [Funcionario] => Array
            (
                [id] => 20
                [matricula] => 5555
                [nome] => JOAO 
                [quantidade] => 
            )

    )

)
```

É possível?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É possível sim. Uma da forma de fazer isto é usar a função [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-unique.php), que tem como propósito retornar um novo *array* sem valores duplicados. Veja um exemplo:

```php
$dupArr = array("A" => "foo", 
                "B" => "baz", 
                "C" => "bar", 
                "D" => "foo"); // Valor repetido
$unique = array_unique($dupArr); 

print_r($unique); // [A] => foo [B] => baz [C] => bar
```

### [**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/19H41s)

### Atualização

Por se tratar de um *array* multidimensional, o `array_unique` não vai funcionar. Será necessário implementar uma função que verifique se um valor existe na *array*, para isto, existe a função [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.in-array.php), mas ela não funciona em *arrays* multidimensionais, portanto, será necessário usá-la de forma [recursiva](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128377/1608936):

```php
function in_array_recursive($agulha, $palheiro) {
    foreach ($palheiro as $item) {
        if (($item == $agulha) || (is_array($item) && in_array_recursive($agulha, $item)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Agora será necessário varrer o *array* com o `foreach` e aplicar a função `in_array_recursive`, para fazer isso, utilize a função abaixo:

```php
function uniqueArray($raiz){
    $unique = [];
    foreach ($raiz as $nodo => $nodos){
        foreach ($nodos as $item => $items){
            foreach ($items as $chave => $valor){
                if (!in_array_recursive($valor, $unique) or empty($valor)){
                    $unique[$nodo][$item][$chave] = $valor;
                } else {
                    unset($unique[$nodo]);
                    break 3;
                }   
            }
        }
    }
    return $unique;
}
```

Utilize a função do seguinte modo:

```php
$dupArray = array(.....);
$unique = uniqueArray($dupArray);

echo "<pre>". print_r($unique, 1). "<pre>";
```

### [**`Exemplo`**](http://ideone.com/Tiwooy)

Comment: Parece um bom código, fiz exatamente isto e o array que retorna vem vazio. ;(

Comment: Parece que seu código funciona perfeitamente. Acredito que em meu não tenha dado certo por alguma inconsistência do array. De qualquer forma já encontrei uma forma deste array não vir por padrão com valores duplicados. Agradeço.