# Como faço para excluir valores repetidos numa array e contar o numero de valores dela

Tags: php

A minha dúvida é bem simples, como faço para excluir valores repetidos de `array`, por exemplo:

```
array = banana,morango,laranja,banana,maca
```

Como faço para excluir, ***1x*** a **banana** de forma a que `array` fique:

```
array = banana,morango,laranja,maca
```

E para terminar, gostava de saber qual a função que conta o número de valores que tem uma `array`?

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62830/remover-valores-duplicados-em-array-multidimensional

Answer (score 2):

```
$unicos = array_unique($array);
$quantidade = count($unicos);
```